# Azure Blob fetch errror after for a Swagger web app

Tags: c#, azure, swagger

I have a web app which generates documentation like Swagger and it tries to get blob content (json as example) to render API definition.

The storage account container is a private container and I set up CORS rule like:

[image]

For blob retrieval:

```
public BlobStorageService(string connectionString)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(connectionString)}' cannot be null or whitespace", nameof(connectionString));
  }

  mBlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
}

public async Task<string> GetBlobUri(string blobName, string tenant)
{
  var blobContainerClient = await GetBlobContainerClient(tenant).ConfigureAwait(true);
  var blockBlobReferance = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  return blockBlobReferance.Uri.ToString();
}

private async Task<BlobContainerClient> GetBlobContainerClient(string tenant)
{
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
  var containerClient = mBlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(tenant);
  if (!await containerClient.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
  {
    containerClient = mBlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(Constants.cDefaultContainerName);
  }

  if (!await containerClient.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
  {
    throw new BlobContainerNotFoundException(tenant);
  }

  return containerClient;
}
```

And I try to get:

```
options.SwaggerEndpoint((await myBlobManager.GetBlobUri("myfile.json", "container"), "Service namespace for myfile.json"); // here I get fetch error
```

[image]

How to solve issue ?

Comment: Please **read the error message**, which says nothing about CORS.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I changed title to be on real question

Comment: is your blob public? because here I'm not sure that your Swagger UI has access to the file

Comment: No, is not public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your container is **not public**, then you cannot directly visit the blobs by using `blob uri`(like this `https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/container/myfile.json`). It will throw "the file does not exist" error.

If you want to visit a blob in a private container, you should append [sas token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#sas-token) at the end of the `blob uri`. To do that, you should modify the code in `GetBlobUri` method, like below:

```
public async Task<string> GetBlobUri(string blobName, string tenant)
{
  var blobContainerClient = await GetBlobContainerClient(tenant).ConfigureAwait(true);
  var blockBlobReferance = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  //for blobs in private container, you should use code below to generate a sas token
  var blob_sas_uri = blockBlobReferance.GenerateSasUri(BlobSasPermissions.All, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1))).ToString();

  return blob_sas_uri;
}
```

Another way is that, you can [set your container access level to public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#set-the-public-access-level-for-a-container).